# How to Change the values of Text fields on the change of option box value

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate

Hiii Guys, I am working on a project which is using Spring MVC and Hibernate framework.  My problem is that I am working on a Form and in the form a Option Box working. I want to change a text field value on change of option box value. 
I already Try this :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#venderid").change(function(){
            $.getJSON("getVenderById.htm", {venderId: $(this).val()},
            function(vender){
                var data = JSON.parse(vender);
                var mail = data.email;
                $("#mail").html(mail);
            }
);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Vender.java**

```
public class Vender {
   private Integer venderid;
     private String vendername;
     private String email;
     private String contact;
    //Setters and getters
}
```

**Controller:-**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getVenderById.htm")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView getVender(@RequestParam("venderId") int vId){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("vender", venderDAO.findById(vId));
        System.out.println("=========Ajax Calling============");
        return mav;
    }
```

Every thing is working fine but how to filled the textbox of e-mail according vender id . Is there any mistake in Callback function , or how to utilize the value of vender object. And one more thing on Apache server console window `========Ajax Calling=======` printing means data is coming from the database. But how do i utilize it please help . And thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your browser's network inspector to see what's actually retured - you need JSON but you're probably getting something different. Use the debugger to probe certain points in your code to verify where the problem starts to show. Include all relevant informtion into the question.

Answer (score 0):

In you ajax callback handler you are expecting vendor, whereas you are sending MAV in your controller. Try doing this in your controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getVenderById.htm")
    @ResponseBody
    public Vender getVender(@RequestParam("venderId") int vId){
        return venderDAO.findById(vId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to minion's answer you need to remove `.htm` as you are expecting JSON in response.

And it's a better practice to use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver and set JSON response as default.

Here is a link [Content Negotiation using Views at spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views)

Comment: i didnt get u .
and i am gonna use your suggestion

Comment: you mean to say , i should remove the `.htm` from request ??

Comment: First of all you need to use @minion's answer.

Comment: And also you'll need to configure Jackson mapper in Spring (it will convert Java object to JSON response), if you did not do it before.

Comment: Am i using right way in jQuery code. ?? I mean my callback function code, please check it.

Comment: how do i configure Jackson mapper in dispatcher-servlet. ??

Comment: It seems ok. Install FireBug and see what http status it returns. Create a breakpoint in java and check if the request comes to controller.

Comment: To configure Jackson mapper you'll need simply add dependencies to pom.xml. And it will be used automatically.

Comment: I am not using Maven.

Comment: Probably gradle? Or what do you use?

Comment: neither gradle nor Maven. Simple web Application in Net Beans , using Jar files for dependencies.

Comment: Anyway even you can download Jar manually and add it to classpath.

Comment: You can download 3 artifacts here and add them to classpath [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core)

Comment: yepp that is was talking about. Thank you.

Comment: after adding in classpath , what should my next step. Any changes in `Dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: Probably I think you should already have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and it should be all what you need. And then minion's answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug or console.log the vender value in the callback like this:

```
function(vender){
       console.log(vender); 
       var data = JSON.parse(vender);
       var mail = data.email;
       $("#mail").html(mail);
}
```

Then copy the value here